# How to change [option + key] international shortcut in OS X

Tags: keyboard

If in OSX text input field pressing <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>  will render `“`, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> will render `æ` and<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> will render `…`.

Can I remap these to render `å`, `ä` and `ö` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you have to use a third party tool: Karabiner.

I have a slightly different proposal for the å though:

In the example below holding the right option key enables the German keyboard layout. Just hold the **right** option key and type <kbd>'</kbd> to get ä and <kbd>;</kbd> to get ö. Releasing the **right** option key switches the layout back to en_US.

To get å simply use <kbd>alt_left</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. Since both keyboard layouts use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to get å you can even print å while <kbd>alt_right</kbd> is pressed -> <kbd>alt_left</kbd><kbd>alt_right</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> prints å.

Prerequisites:

The en-US **and** the de-DE keyboard layout have to be enabled. The shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> mustn't be used elsewhere than "Switch to previous input source" **but** one may change this easily.

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <item>
       <name>Change input source temporarily</name>
       <item>
         <name>Change input source to German while you are holding down the right option key.</name>
         <identifier>remap.change_input_source_temporary_german_option_r</identifier>
         <autogen>
           __KeyToKey__
           KeyCode::OPTION_R,
           KeyCode::VK_NONE,
           Option::KEYTOKEY_BEFORE_KEYDOWN, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_GERMAN, KeyCode::VK_WAIT_100MS,
           Option::KEYTOKEY_AFTER_KEYUP, KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::VK_WAIT_100MS,
         </autogen>
       </item>
     </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

---

This may interfere with other uses of <kbd>alt_right</kbd><kbd>key</kbd>!

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this post when trying to achieve the same mapping with Karabiner-Elements. 
The old "Karabiner" does not work with Sierra and above and have been replaced with Karabiner-Elements.

I managed to achieve the behaviour desired by original poster in Karabinier-Elements by adding the configuration below to karabinier.conf so I posted this as reference for others that stumble in here for same reason.

It is based on the "standard" way to enter umlaut characters with a US keyboard, e.g.
<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> => ä
<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> => ö
and
<kbd>option</kbd>+a => å

```
(in section "complex_modification" -> "rules")
"rules": [
       {"description": "left_option ['; to åäö",
        "manipulators": [
            {"type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "open_bracket",
                "modifiers": { "mandatory": [ "left_option" ] }
            },
            "to": [
                {"key_code": "a",
                 "modifiers" : [ "left_option" ]
                }]
            },
            {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "open_bracket",
                "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_option",
                    "left_shift"
                ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {"key_code": "a",
                 "modifiers" : [
                 "left_option",
                 "left_shift"
                 ]

                }
            ]
            },

            {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "quote",
                "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_option"
                ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {"key_code": "u",
                 "modifiers" : [
                 "left_option"
                 ]
                },
                {"key_code": "a"}
            ]
            },
            {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "quote",
                "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_option",
                    "left_shift"
                ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {"key_code": "u",
                 "modifiers" : [
                 "left_option"
                 ]
                },
                {"key_code": "a",
                 "modifiers" : [ "left_shift" ]}
            ]
            },

            {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "semicolon",
                "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_option"
                ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {"key_code": "u",
                 "modifiers" : [
                 "left_option"
                 ]
                },
                {"key_code": "o"}
            ]
            },

            {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "semicolon",
                "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_option",
                    "left_shift"
                ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {"key_code": "u",
                 "modifiers" : [
                 "left_option"
                 ]
                },
                {"key_code": "o",
                 "modifiers" : [ "left_shift" ]}
            ]
            }
        ]
        }] // end "rules"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have successfully made this working like intended by @klanomath, but transferred to Karabiner-Elements. In my version, I am using ABC by default (US) and switching to Swedish-Pro while holding right command.

I add a json file called `johan.json` (any name.json would do) to `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications` with the following content. Modify as you please!

```
{
  "title": "Personal Johan Remapping",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "While using US keymap, holding right command temporarily switches to the Swedish qwerty layout.",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "right_command",
            "modifiers": {
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "input_source_if",
              "input_sources": [
                {
                  "input_source_id": "^com\\.apple\\.keylayout\\.ABC$"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "to": [
            {
              "select_input_source": {
                "input_source_id": "^com\\.apple\\.keylayout\\.Swedish-Pro$"
              }
            }
          ],
          "to_after_key_up": [
            {
              "select_input_source": {
                "input_source_id": "^com\\.apple\\.keylayout\\.ABC$"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, in Karabiner-Elements UI, under Complex modifications, click Add rule and select the rule you created. You will also need to have the corresponding keylayouts selected in System Preferences.